# SQL procedure that is returning all Products that belong to a Department through Category

Tags: mysql, sql

At least that is what I think it's doing. I'm not sure how to call the prodcedure with the right parameters.

Here is the SQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_products_on_department(
  IN inDepartmentId INT, IN inShortProductDescriptionLength INT,
  IN inProductsPerPage INT, IN inStartItem INT)
BEGIN
  PREPARE statement FROM
    "SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, p.name,
                     IF(LENGTH(p.description) <= ?,
                        p.description,
                        CONCAT(LEFT(p.description, ?),
                               '...')) AS description,
                     p.price, p.discounted_price, p.thumbnail
     FROM            product p
     INNER JOIN      product_category pc
                       ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
     INNER JOIN      category c
                       ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
     WHERE           (p.display = 2 OR p.display = 3)
                     AND c.department_id = ?
     ORDER BY        p.display DESC
     LIMIT           ?, ?";

  SET @p1 = inShortProductDescriptionLength;
  SET @p2 = inShortProductDescriptionLength;
  SET @p3 = inDepartmentId;
  SET @p4 = inStartItem;
  SET @p5 = inProductsPerPage;

  EXECUTE statement USING @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5;
END$$
```

And here is a snippet of the Schema:

[image]

This is what happens when I try to call the procedure with the following parameters:

```
inDepartmentId: 1,
inShortProductDescriptionLength: 10,
inProductsPerPage: 10,
nStartItem: 1

The following query has failed: "SET @p0='1'; SET @p1='10'; SET @p2='10'; SET @p3='1'; CALL `catalog_get_products_on_department`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); "

MySQL said: #3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'turing.p.display' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

Comment: Hm. Maybe I'm missing something but I suppose that **"... column 'turing.p.display' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT"** tells that it's needed to either:  a) add `turing.pg.display` into list of columns of `SELECT` or  b) to remove `DISTINCT`. And params are not relevant for this error

Comment: I removed the ORDER BY expression and now it seems to work. I'm not sure what the product.display property is

Comment: So you choose not to cure problem but eliminate the source completely. Good if it works for you. But  the ordering of output could change completely or maybe even becomes random

Comment: I put p.display into the list the columns and it wors with the ORDER BY. if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I summarized each possible way to eliminate problem just like boring nerd I am ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Error message:

> MySQL said: #3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'turing.p.display' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

tells it's needed to:

#### a. Add column `turing.p.display` into list of columns

so that statement becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, p.name,
                 IF(LENGTH(p.description) <= ?,
                    p.description,
                    CONCAT(LEFT(p.description, ?),
                           '...')) AS description,
                 p.price, p.discounted_price, p.thumbnail,
                 p.display 
 FROM            product p
 INNER JOIN      product_category pc
                   ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
 INNER JOIN      category c
                   ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
 WHERE           (p.display = 2 OR p.display = 3)
                 AND c.department_id = ?
 ORDER BY        p.display DESC
 LIMIT           ?, ?";
```

(note added new column `p.display`

or

#### b. Remove `DISTINCT`

This must eliminate error message but could add duplicates to output.

#### c. Remove `ORDER BY` completely

This certainly eliminates the cause of error but ordering of data could change or even became random (depending on physical organisation of tables/indexes, versions, phase of moon, etc)

I suppose that **"a"** is the best in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty obvious:

```
ORDER BY p.display DESC
```

`p.display` is not in the `SELECT`.  This is needed because you have `SELECT DISTINCT`.

I think the simplest way around this is to use `GROUP BY`:

```
select . . .
from . . .
group by p.product_id, p.name, description,
         p.price, p.discounted_price, p.thumbnail
order by max(p.display) desc
```